# Can sfcgal be Installed on Amazon Web Services

Tags: postgis, amazon-web-services, sfcgal

We're trying to set up a cloud-based repository using postgresql, postgis and sfcgal. While I have these installed and running on my laptop, it looks like AWS RDS does not support sfcgal.

Is this so?

If not, what approach is needed to add the sfcgal extension to postgresql on AWS?

Could it work on another cloud service?

Comment: On AWS? Certainly. In an RDS? Probably not. Please [edit] the question to clarify your environment.

Answer (score 2):

You can install virtually the same set of software in AWS EC2 as that of your laptop. At least, this is the case for me with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, in which [sfcgal works out of the box](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/179618/34474) with `apt-get`.

You can also install sfcgal by [compiling it from source](http://oslandia.github.io/SFCGAL/installation.html).

-- Update --

As pointed out in the comments by @vince, if you are using RDS, it does not provide access to the host OS on which the PG service is running. Compiling new binaries is not an option.

From the [RDS FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/postgresql/faqs/), you can send request to AWS for installing additional extensions:

> Q: What are the extensions supported by RDS for PostgreSQL?
>
> You can check the list of supported extensions in the Amazon RDS User
>   Guide. To request support for additional extensions, you can send an
>   email to rds-postgres-extensions-request@amazon.com with the extension
>   name and use case.

Comment: Yes, but our context is AWS RDS PostgreSQL db engine as a service, which I didn't mention earlier, not a bare EC2.

Comment: RDS (relarional database as a service) does not provide access to the host on which the PG service is running. It provides a fixed, and limited, set of extensions. Compiling new binaries is not an option.