# Selecting the longest connected lines from PostGIS ST_ApproximateMedialAxis

Tags: postgis, sql, topology, dissolve, connectivity-analysis

I used PostGIS [`ST_ApproximateMedialAxis`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ApproximateMedialAxis.html) to transform polygons representing mountain ranges into a series of lines.  Now, I'd like to select only the "longest" line segment for each group, so that I can dissolve the lines and use it for "curved" labeling.  Can I extend the query in PostGIS to end up with the single series of arcs?

The end result should look something like the lines highlighted in yellow in the picture below.

[image: Connected Lines]

Comment: the *ultimate* solution to this (and sweet sugar to many more of PostGIS' functions and functionality) is building and enabling the [SFCGAL](http://www.sfcgal.org/) backend [for PostGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/167687/how-to-enable-sfcgal-in-postgis) (with default GEOS, the medial axis is directly derived off the `ST_StraightSkeleton`)...but that *can* be a massive pain...

Comment: I'm using Postgres 9.5 and PostGIS 2.3, and have installed the postgis_sfcgal extension, thus allowing me to use ST_ApproximateMedialAxis.  I chose Medial Axis results because the StraightSkeleton had so many more "fishbones" coming in from the sides of the polygons

Comment: What do you mean by each group? Do you have a groupid or somesuch? Perhaps you should post the SQL you have run so far.

Comment: Instead of"group", perhaps I could have used "set", as in "set of connected arcs".  For example, in the picture there are 3 "sets", and the longest axis of arcs are highlighted in yellow.

Comment: In that case, you probably want to use one of the clustering functions, [DBScan](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.4/ST_ClusterDBSCAN.html), for example, to create the sets/groups, and  then do a max(length) ... group by set kind of thing. It is a window function, so you can get a group ID out of it quite naturally.

Answer (score 5):

I am publishing my answer for those who visit this page hoping to find an answer to the problem you have formulated!

So, I invite everyone to fly with me in a plane with the engine I have assembled with the name: "Free and Magic geoSQL", in order to admire the beautiful mountain scenery of the Cordillera mountain system and from a height of flight to see their centerlines :-)! We have a difficult and interesting task ahead of us, but we can do it even without `SFCGAL` library and `ST_ApproximateMedialAxis` and `ST_StraightSkeleton` functions, because we are pilots and navigators of high class :-), I strongly hope so! I command: "Fasten your seatbelts", "From the screw", "Fly"! and of course I start the engine, which works so far for only one polygon:

```
WITH
tbla AS (SELECT (ST_Dump(geom)).geom FROM <name_polygon_table>),
tblb AS (SELECT (ST_DumpPoints(geom)).geom FROM tbla),
tblc AS (SELECT ((ST_Dump(ST_VoronoiPolygons(ST_Collect(geom)))).geom) geom FROM tblb),
tbld AS (SELECT (ST_Dump(ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom))).geom FROM tblc a JOIN tbla b ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)),
tble AS (SELECT line1, line2, CASE WHEN line1>line2 THEN line1 WHEN line1<=line2 THEN line2 END FROM (SELECT ST_MakeLine((ST_PointN(ST_Boundary(ST_OrientedEnvelope(geom)),1)),
(ST_PointN(ST_Boundary(ST_OrientedEnvelope(geom)),2))) AS line1, ST_MakeLine((ST_PointN(ST_Boundary(ST_OrientedEnvelope(geom)),2)), (ST_PointN(ST_Boundary(ST_OrientedEnvelope(geom)),3))) AS line2 FROM tbla) AS foo),
tblf AS (SELECT (ST_Buffer(line2, ST_Length(line2), 'endcap=flat join=round')) geom FROM tble),
tblg AS (SELECT DISTINCT (ST_Dump(ST_Difference(a.geom, b.geom))).geom FROM tblf a JOIN tbla b ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)),
tblh AS (SELECT (ST_Dump(ST_Buffer(geom, -0.000001))).geom geom FROM tblg),
tbli AS (SELECT (ST_Buffer(geom, 0.000002)) geom FROM tblh a JOIN tble b ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.line2)),
tblj AS (SELECT ST_ExteriorRing(ST_Union(a.geom)) geom FROM tbld a JOIN tbli b ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)),
tblk AS (SELECT ST_MakeLine(pt1, pt2) geom FROM (SELECT ST_PointN(geom, generate_series(1, ST_NPoints(geom)-1)) pt1, ST_PointN(geom, generate_series(2, ST_NPoints(geom))) pt2 FROM tblj) AS geom),
tbll AS (SELECT (ST_Dump(ST_Intersection(ST_Buffer(a.geom, -0.0001), b.geom))).geom FROM tbla a JOIN tblk b ON ST_Contains(a.geom, b.geom))
SELECT ST_Union(geom) geom FROM tbll
```

(If necessary, adjust it to the size of your polygons (function `ST_Buffer`), I played with data in EPSG:4326).

From now on, everyone will be able to see and create the centerline of the polygon.

Original solutions.

The script is called: `ST_LongestAxisPolygonsFromVoronoiDiagrams`.

(**!Not to use for simple shapes like rectangle!**)

***"I want to thank all those who contribute to the creation and development of promising geoinstruments by sharing their ideas and codes..."***

*First editing:*

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ST_LongestAxisPolygonsFromVoronoiDiagrams(
    geom GEOMETRY
)
RETURNS GEOMETRY AS
$BODY$
WITH
tbla AS (SELECT (ST_Dump(geom)).geom),
tblb AS (SELECT (ST_DumpPoints(geom)).geom FROM tbla),
tblc AS (SELECT ((ST_Dump(ST_VoronoiPolygons(ST_Collect(geom)))).geom) geom FROM tblb),
tbld AS (SELECT (ST_Dump(ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom))).geom FROM tblc a JOIN tbla b ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)),
tble AS (SELECT line1, line2, CASE WHEN line1>line2 THEN line1 WHEN line1<=line2 THEN line2 END FROM (SELECT ST_MakeLine((ST_PointN(ST_Boundary(ST_OrientedEnvelope(geom)),1)),
(ST_PointN(ST_Boundary(ST_OrientedEnvelope(geom)),2))) AS line1, ST_MakeLine((ST_PointN(ST_Boundary(ST_OrientedEnvelope(geom)),2)), (ST_PointN(ST_Boundary(ST_OrientedEnvelope(geom)),3))) AS line2 FROM tbla) AS foo),
tblf AS (SELECT (ST_Buffer(line2, ST_Length(line2), 'endcap=flat join=round')) geom FROM tble),
tblg AS (SELECT DISTINCT (ST_Dump(ST_Difference(a.geom, b.geom))).geom FROM tblf a JOIN tbla b ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)),
tblh AS (SELECT (ST_Dump(ST_Buffer(geom, -0.000001))).geom geom FROM tblg),
tbli AS (SELECT (ST_Buffer(geom, 0.000002)) geom FROM tblh a JOIN tble b ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.line2)),
tblj AS (SELECT ST_ExteriorRing(ST_Union(a.geom)) geom FROM tbld a JOIN tbli b ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)),
tblk AS (SELECT ST_MakeLine(pt1, pt2) geom FROM (SELECT ST_PointN(geom, generate_series(1, ST_NPoints(geom)-1)) pt1, ST_PointN(geom, generate_series(2, ST_NPoints(geom))) pt2 FROM tblj) AS geom),
tbll AS (SELECT (ST_Dump(ST_Intersection(ST_Buffer(a.geom, -0.0001), b.geom))).geom FROM tbla a JOIN tblk b ON ST_Contains(a.geom, b.geom))
SELECT ST_Union(geom) geom FROM tbll
$BODY$
LANGUAGE SQL;
```

RUN

```
SELECT ST_LongestAxisPolygonsFromVoronoiDiagrams(geom) geom FROM <source_table>
```

If necessary, make the line smoother, add the function generate_series...

*Second edition 13.03.2020*

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ST_LongestAxisPolygonsFromVoronoiDiagrams_gs(
    geom GEOMETRY,
    n integer)
RETURNS GEOMETRY AS
$BODY$
WITH
    tbla AS (SELECT (ST_Dump(geom)).geom),
    tblb AS (WITH btbl AS (SELECT (ST_ExteriorRing(((ST_Dump(geom)).geom))) geom),
            intervals AS (SELECT generate_series (0, n) as steps)
            SELECT steps AS stp, ST_LineInterpolatePoint(geom, steps/(SELECT count(steps)::float-1 FROM intervals)) geom FROM btbl, intervals GROUP BY intervals.steps, geom),
    tblc AS (SELECT ((ST_Dump(ST_VoronoiPolygons(ST_Collect(geom)))).geom) geom FROM tblb),
    tbld AS (SELECT (ST_Dump(ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom))).geom FROM tblc a JOIN tbla b ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)),
    tble AS (SELECT line1, line2 FROM (SELECT ST_MakeLine((ST_PointN(ST_Boundary(ST_OrientedEnvelope(geom)),1)),
        (ST_PointN(ST_Boundary(ST_OrientedEnvelope(geom)),2))) AS line1, ST_MakeLine((ST_PointN(ST_Boundary(ST_OrientedEnvelope(geom)),2)), (ST_PointN(ST_Boundary(ST_OrientedEnvelope(geom)),3))) AS line2 FROM tbla) AS foo),
    tblf AS (SELECT (ST_Buffer(line2, ST_Length(line2), 'endcap=flat join=round')) geom FROM tble),
    tblg AS (SELECT DISTINCT (ST_Dump(ST_Difference(a.geom, b.geom))).geom FROM tblf a JOIN tbla b ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)),
    tblh AS (SELECT (ST_Dump(ST_Buffer(geom, -0.000001))).geom geom FROM tblg),
    tbli AS (SELECT (ST_Buffer(geom, 0.000002)) geom FROM tblh a JOIN tble b ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.line2)),
    tblj AS (SELECT ST_ExteriorRing(ST_Union(a.geom)) geom FROM tbld a JOIN tbli b ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)),
    tblk AS (SELECT ST_MakeLine(pt1, pt2) geom FROM (SELECT ST_PointN(geom, generate_series(1, ST_NPoints(geom)-1)) pt1, ST_PointN(geom, generate_series(2, ST_NPoints(geom))) pt2 FROM tblj) AS geom),
    tbll AS (SELECT (ST_Dump(ST_Intersection(ST_Buffer(a.geom, -0.0001), b.geom))).geom FROM tbla a JOIN tblk b ON ST_Contains(a.geom, b.geom))
            SELECT ST_MakeLine(ST_Centroid(geom)) geom FROM tbll
$BODY$
LANGUAGE SQL;
```

RUN

```
SELECT ST_LongestAxisPolygonsFromVoronoiDiagrams_gs(geom, 300) geom FROM <source_table>
```

*Third edition 30.03.2020*

As an option, for 2 or more polygons run the following script:

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.geom
FROM <source_table> AS a
JOIN LATERAL (SELECT ST_LongestAxisPolygonsFromVoronoiDiagrams_gs(geom) AS geom
FROM <source_table>) AS b ON true;
```

*Fourth edition 13.05.2021*

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ST_CentraLAxisLongestLineFromPolygons_VD(
geom GEOMETRY,
n integer)
RETURNS GEOMETRY AS
$BODY$
WITH
    tbla AS (SELECT (ST_Dump(geom)).geom geom),
    tblb AS (SELECT ST_Buffer(ST_Boundary(ST_OrientedEnvelope(geom)),0.00001) geom FROM tbla),
    tblc AS (SELECT (ST_Dump(ST_Difference(ST_Boundary(a.geom), b.geom))).geom geom FROM tbla a JOIN tblb b ON true),
    tbld AS (SELECT (ST_Dump(ST_Difference(ST_Buffer(ST_OrientedEnvelope(a.geom), -0.00001), b.geom))).geom geom FROM tbla a JOIN tbla b ON true),
    tble AS (SELECT ST_Buffer(geom, 0.00001) geom  FROM (SELECT ST_MakeLine((ST_PointN(ST_Boundary(ST_OrientedEnvelope(geom)),1)),
        (ST_PointN(ST_Boundary(ST_OrientedEnvelope(geom)),4))) AS geom FROM tbla) AS foo),
    tblf AS (SELECT generate_series (0, n) as steps),
    tblg AS (SELECT steps AS stp, ST_LineInterpolatePoint(geom, steps/(SELECT count(steps)::float-1 FROM tblf)) geom FROM tblc, tblf GROUP BY tblf.steps, geom),
    tblh AS (SELECT ((ST_Dump(ST_VoronoiPolygons(ST_Collect(geom)))).geom) geom FROM tblg),
    tbli AS (SELECT (a.geom) geom FROM tbld a JOIN tble b ON ST_Intersects(a.geom,  ST_Buffer(b.geom, 0.00001))),
    tblj AS (SELECT ST_ExteriorRing(ST_Union(a.geom)) geom FROM tblh a JOIN tbli b ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom))
            SELECT ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom) geom FROM tblj a JOIN tbla b ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom);
$BODY$
LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Run

```
SELECT ST_CentraLAxisLongestLineFromPolygons_VD(geom, 100) AS geom FROM <source_table>
```