# Selecting connected lines between start and end point in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, select, connectivity-analysis

Is there a method in QGIS to select all connected lines that are between a start and end feature (point or selected lines)?

I imagine a workflow going something like this:

1. Choose the starting line feature
2. Choose the ending line feature
3. Run a process that will select all features (between the start and end) that are connected.

The end result would look something highlighted yellow lines in the picture below, assuming I had pre-selected lines at the beginning and end of the now highlighted arcs.

[image]

This is an alternative method: [How do I select the longest connected lines from PostGIS ST_ApproximateMedialAxis?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/295199)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution that I can think of is to calculate the shortest path between two points using the **Road Graph** plugin.

You can find a full example of the usage of the plugin here [7.3. Lesson: Network Analysis - QGIS](https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/training_manual/vector_analysis/network_analysis.html)

[image: Start and end points]

[image: The result of the Road Graph plugin]

Comment: I thought I had tried the road graph tool before, but I'll have to try again.  Thank you for including the link to the tutorial.

Comment: The RoadGrpah tool worked great!  Clearly I did something wrong the first time I tried it.  Thank you for the nudge I needed to try it again.

Comment: You are welcome Ryan! Glad to hear that it worked for you.

Comment: I do not understand why it has to be complicated to select all lines in between selected points or lines. In JOSM, it is as simple as Shift + click (Ctrl+click selects individual lines).

Answer (score -1):

It depends on how your data where produced. If they follow an order you could try this:

1. Select first and last segments with ctrl + selection tool.
2. Execute a selection expresion like this:

[image]

Comment: Interesting method, I'll have to look into this further.  It was created with ST_ApproximateMedialAxis from PostGIS, so I'm not sure how the attributes are coded.