# How does ST_ApproximateMedialAxis(geometry) calculate medial axis internally?

Tags: postgis, sfcgal, medial-axis

I am curious about the internal working of `ST_ApproximateMedialAxis(geometry)` when a complex polygon is passed to this function.

How does it calculate the medial axis internally?

Comment: Have you consulted its documentation?  If so, please link to it, and describe precisely where you expected to find your answer and what, if anything, was there.

Comment: The [medial axis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medial_axis) is a point set predicate and its computation rather well defined. PostGIS (GEOS/SFCGAL) does not significantly deviate from the established algorithms.

Comment: There is a story about making one implementation in https://github.com/MapServer/MapServer/wiki/Medial-Axis-Approximation and in the comments of the referred pull request.

Comment: See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/409483/simplify-a-branching-line-string for a QA related to that PR

Answer (score 3):

The PostGIS `ST_ApproximateMedialAxis` uses the SFCGAL `approximateMedialAxis` function (code [here](https://gitlab.com/Oslandia/SFCGAL/-/blob/master/src/algorithm/straightSkeleton.cpp#L356)).  This function computes the [straight skeleton](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Straight_skeleton_2/index.html#title4) using CGAL. It then returns only skeleton edges which are considered to form the medial axis according to the logic in [this function](https://gitlab.com/Oslandia/SFCGAL/-/blob/master/src/algorithm/straightSkeleton.cpp#L109).