Remove side branches from linestring
I'm trying to create a centerline from a (curved) polygon. To do this I'm using the PostGIS ST_ApproximateMedialAxis tool. However, this creates a lot of side branches, whereas I only want to keep the main line.

It can be a PostGIS solution, as long as it can be implemented in Python. Other Python solutions are also possible. I have to be able to automate it, so manual removal in QGIS is not possible.
I've tried several other centerline options, but all of them create side branches. The approximate medial axis tool has the 'nicest' line, with the fewest side branches, but still there's a lot. I really have no idea how I could remove these, so I haven't tried any solutions for this yet.

Unfortunately, 'centerlines' of arbitrary aerial geometries are too ambiguous to be generalized. The approximate medial axis is a specific and well defined point set theoretic algorithm that can only be considered as having an apparent 'effect' of something like a 'centerline'. In your case, switching to graph theory and identifying the 'dangles' by looking at vertex intersection counts might help.

You can do it with a shortest path routing algorithm - see https://blog.ianturton.com/geotools/geoserver/2021/09/26/Centrelines-part2.html for an example, though it's in java

If you want a postgis solution, you could try pgrouting.  Create a network topology from the lines, then get the shortest path between the start and end points that you specify.

NetworkX is a python package for creating network graphs.  It has shortest path algorithms.

See this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/409483/simplify-a-branching-line-string/411926

in particular see this answer https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/411894/79

Build a networkx Graph, find its end nodes, for all pairwise combinations of end nodes, find the longest path:
from shapely.wkt import loads
from shapely.geometry import Point
from shapely.ops import unary_union
import networkx as nx
import geopandas as gpd
from itertools import combinations

#Create a multiline geometry
wkt = "MULTILINESTRING((521164 6590033, 521160 6590013), (521149 6590000, 521157 6589998), (520001 6589473, 520010 6589488), (520174 6589381, 520191 6589398), (521246 6589581, 521215 6589604), (520534 6589448, 520553 6589441), (520534 6589448, 520524 6589461), (520233 6589383, 520219 6589425), (519825 6589217, 519822 6589225), (521160 6590013, 521158 6590004), (520553 6589441, 520583 6589442), (521158 6590004, 521157 6590000), (520478 6589470, 520439 6589461), (520478 6589470, 520492 6589469), (519822 6589225, 519821 6589228), (521157 6590000, 521157 6589998), (519821 6589228, 519823 6589254), (520492 6589469, 520516 6589468), (520524 6589461, 520521 6589466), (521157 6589998, 521155 6589945), (520401 6589431, 520397 6589448), (520521 6589467, 520517 6589468), (520521 6589467, 520521 6589466), (521038 6589613, 521124 6589590), (521038 6589613, 521021 6589627), (520516 6589468, 520517 6589468), (520010 6589488, 519997 6589515), (521155 6589945, 521156 6589943), (520724 6589575, 520725 6589607), (520724 6589575, 520717 6589546), (521156 6589943, 521180 6589822), (520724 6589617, 520721 6589627), (520724 6589617, 520725 6589607), (520580 6589431, 520583 6589442), (520721 6589627, 520716 6589688), (520717 6589546, 520706 6589524), (519855 6589283, 519832 6589293), (520439 6589461, 520431 6589458), (521021 6589627, 521009 6589641), (521180 6589822, 521202 6589728), (519823 6589254, 519832 6589293), (521009 6589641, 520965 6589695), (521202 6589728, 521207 6589710), (520191 6589398, 520209 6589427), (520431 6589458, 520418 6589454), (521207 6589710, 521220 6589666), (521189 6589583, 521204 6589592), (521189 6589583, 521132 6589589), (521124 6589590, 521132 6589589), (520418 6589454, 520397 6589448), (520311 6589439, 520290 6589436), (520311 6589439, 520397 6589448), (520706 6589524, 520705 6589522), (520290 6589436, 520261 6589433), (520583 6589442, 520588 6589444), (521220 6589666, 521223 6589658), (520965 6589695, 520955 6589706), (520705 6589522, 520631 6589468), (521223 6589658, 521223 6589656), (520955 6589706, 520888 6589768), (520588 6589444, 520631 6589468), (521223 6589656, 521217 6589610), (520261 6589433, 520236 6589426), (520716 6589688, 520717 6589691), (520717 6589691, 520745 6589756), (521204 6589592, 521206 6589594), (521206 6589594, 521215 6589604), (520193 6589433, 520201 6589436), (519888 6589508, 519900 6589483), (520236 6589426, 520219 6589425), (521217 6589610, 521215 6589604), (520014 6589518, 520006 6589516), (520014 6589518, 520024 6589517), (520029 6589518, 520038 6589523), (520029 6589518, 520024 6589517), (519832 6589293, 519831 6589303), (519932 6589482, 519966 6589507), (519932 6589482, 519923 6589482), (519832 6589329, 519833 6589326), (519832 6589329, 519832 6589360), (520006 6589516, 520003 6589516), (520003 6589516, 520001 6589516), (519833 6589326, 519833 6589322), (520001 6589516, 519997 6589515), (519833 6589322, 519831 6589303), (519997 6589515, 519966 6589507), (519868 6589443, 519864 6589437), (519868 6589443, 519875 6589449), (519882 6589457, 519888 6589468), (519882 6589457, 519875 6589449), (520888 6589768, 520857 6589790), (519864 6589437, 519862 6589434), (519862 6589434, 519836 6589394), (520857 6589790, 520817 6589805), (519923 6589482, 519921 6589482), (519832 6589360, 519836 6589394), (520038 6589523, 520053 6589528), (519921 6589482, 519900 6589483), (520198 6589441, 520180 6589458), (520198 6589441, 520200 6589437), (520200 6589437, 520201 6589436), (519888 6589468, 519900 6589483), (520201 6589436, 520209 6589427), (520219 6589425, 520209 6589427), (520180 6589458, 520154 6589485), (520754 6589766, 520745 6589756), (520754 6589766, 520780 6589790), (520780 6589790, 520807 6589807), (520053 6589528, 520073 6589528), (520817 6589805, 520807 6589807), (520806 6589813, 520807 6589807), (520154 6589485, 520149 6589489), (520149 6589489, 520112 6589510), (520086 6589522, 520073 6589528), (520086 6589522, 520112 6589510))"
line_geometry = loads(wkt)
ax = gpd.GeoSeries([line_geometry]).plot(figsize=(15,15), linewidth=1, zorder=1, color="gray")


#Split the multiline into individual single part lines.
# For each line, extract the start and end coordinates.
# Use them to create an edge and attach line length and line geometry as edge attributes
G = nx.Graph()
single_lines = list(line_geometry.geoms)
for single_line in single_lines:
    start, stop = single_line.coords #(520086.0, 6589522.0), (520112.0, 6589510.0)
    G.add_edge(start, stop, weight=single_line.length, geometry=single_line)

#End nodes have a degree of 1. List them and plot
end_nodes = [n for n in G.nodes if G.degree[n]==1]
gpd.GeoSeries([Point(n) for n in end_nodes]).plot(ax=ax, color="green", markersize=15, zorder=3)


#For each pairwise combination of nodes, find the shortest path between them, store the path and
# its length in "paths" list.
paths = []
for n1, n2 in combinations(end_nodes, 2):
    path = nx.shortest_path(G, source=n1, target=n2, weight="weight") #[(519888.0, 6589508.0), (519900.0, 6589483.0), ..., (519921.0, 6589482.0)]
    length = nx.path_weight(G, path, "weight") #1252.7584697077757
    paths.append([path, length])

paths.sort(key=lambda x: x[1]) #Sort the list from shortest to longest path
longest_path, longest_length = paths[-1] #Select the longest = last path in the list

#For node1 node2, then node2 node3, ... , extract the geometry from the edge_data 
#   and store in path_segemts list
path_segments = []
for n1, n2 in zip(longest_path, longest_path[1:]):
    path_segments.append(G.get_edge_data(n1, n2)["geometry"])

longest_line = unary_union(path_segments) #Union the individual lines into one geometry

#Plot it
s = gpd.GeoSeries([longest_line])
s.plot(ax=ax, color="red", linewidth=3)


