# ERROR: function st_issolid(geometry) does not exist

Tags: postgis

My goal is to calculate the volume of a room whose geometry is POLYHEDRALSURFACE. 
First, I tried to use "ST_Volume" on my geom directly and got the following error  "ERROR:  function st_volume(geometry) does not exist".
Then, I checked my geom is solid or not by using "ST_IsSolid", still got error "ERROR:  function st_issolid(geometry) does not exist".

My PostGIS version is 2.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both functions need the SFCGAL backend

- https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Volume.html
- https://postgis.net/docs/ST_IsSolid.html

See the answers to this question: [How to enable SFCGAL in PostGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/167687/how-to-enable-sfcgal-in-postgis)

Information in the docs about PostGIS backends: https://postgis.net/docs/postgis_backend.html

There are other SFCGAL functions listed here: https://postgis.net/docs/reference.html#reference_sfcgal